# Convert string representation of a Dictionary to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I know that there are already several posts with similar questions, but I have not found a post that can solve my specific problem.

I extracted a string representation of a dictionary via web scraping and stored it in a variable called data.

The raw data looks like this and is a string.

{"label":"Ländergewichtungen des Fonds","asOfDate":"per 17 Feb 2022","asOfDateSimple":"17 Feb 2022","attrArray":[{"name":{"label":"Land","value":"USA"},"weight":{"label":"Gewichtung","value":"59,30%"}},{"name":{"label":"Land","value":"Japan"},"weight":{"label":"Gewichtung","value":"5,86%"}} ...etc

I want to extract the name and weight for each country and store it in a pandas data frame.

| Land | Gewichtung |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 59,30% |
| Japan | 5,86% |

Because the countries and percentages can change over time, calling them by name is not an option.

So far I tried multiple slice options, the ast (ast.literal_eval(data)) and json (json_acceptable_string = data.replace('"', """)) module, but couldn't get it to work.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


url = "https://www.ssga.com/de/de/institutional/etfs/funds/spdr-msci-acwi-imi-ucits-etf-spyi-gy"

headers = *User-Agent removed for privacy reasons*

request = requests.get(url,headers = headers)   
   
acwi = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"lxml")


data = acwi.find("input",{"id": "fund-geographical-breakdown" } ).get("value")
```

It returns the string above.

I would be very grateful if someone has an idea how to extract the country and weighting. If I have missed a post where this question has already been answered, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to extract the values:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ssga.com/de/de/institutional/etfs/funds/spdr-msci-acwi-imi-ucits-etf-spyi-gy"

acwi = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
data = acwi.find("input", {"id": "fund-geographical-breakdown"}).get("value")

df = pd.read_json(data)["attrArray"].apply(pd.Series)
df["name"] = df["name"].str["value"]
df["weight"] = df["weight"].str["value"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     name  weight
0                     USA  59,30%
1                   Japan   5,86%
2          Großbritannien   4,19%
3                   China   3,32%
4                  Kanada   3,26%
5              Frankreich   2,72%
6                 Schweiz   2,71%
7             Deutschland   2,17%
8              Australien   2,11%

...
```